# npm and git command lines are very slow on Windows; how can I sort out why?

Tags: node.js, windows, git, bash, npm

I suspect it's Symantec Endpoint Protection but the evidence I have is inconclusive and support seems to think it's all fine. For instance:

```
$ date && npm test && date
Thu Aug 24 13:58:37 PDT 2017

> gamma-listener@0.2.0 test C:\work\gamma-listener
> lab -Rv  -e development -r console ./test/unit

...

9 tests complete (2 skipped)
Test duration: 267 ms
Assertions count: 24 (verbosity: 2.67)
No global variable leaks detected

Thu Aug 24 13:58:53 PDT 2017
```

So the tests took <0.5s but the whole thing took 15s. That seems extreme. I'm used to 9 tests running in under 1s total on my Mac. This is bash on Windows. It's not hitting a proxy, this is all local (unit tests).

How can I sort out what is taking so long? Can I prove that SEP is causing the slowdown?

`Win 10, bash 4.3.46, Node 6.11.2, npm 3.10.10`

I can't upgrade Node for another month or so. Kinda doubt that's the issue.

Comment: @JackDelson hahahah GNU is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same trouble.  Try disabling Symantec.  For me the command is: `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\smc.exe" -stop` .

In Powershell, I like to measure the performance of git status, both before and after that change: `Measure-Command { git status }`